# Tap Local Notifications isn't triggered

Tags: ios10, uilocalnotification, appdelegate

In iOS 10.3 I'm adding the code, to the `AppDelegate`:

```
@interface AppDelegate () {
    UNUserNotificationCenter *center;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
    UNAuthorizationOptions options = UNAuthorizationOptionAlert + UNAuthorizationOptionSound;
    [center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:options
                          completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                              if (!granted) {
                                  DLog(@"Something went wrong");
                              } else {
                                  DLog(@"Access Granted")
                              }
                          }];

    return YES;
}
```

I tap the notification but the method bellow isn't called.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Register for notification import `UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h` framework in `AppDelegate` and use Notification Delegate `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` to respond to notifications when notifications receive.

```
@interface AppDelegate ()<UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate>

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    //Notification Setup.
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 10.0) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
        center.delegate = self;
        [center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge) completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error){
            if( !error ){
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
            }
        }];
    } else {

        //register to receive notifications
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound) categories:nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];

    }


    return YES;
}

#ifdef __IPHONE_10_0
////####    iOS 10    #########//
//This is call when application is open.
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
       willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler
{
    NSLog(@"Userinfo %@",notification.request.content.userInfo);
}


//This is call when application is in background.
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response
         withCompletionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler
{
    NSLog(@"Userinfo %@",response.notification.request.content.userInfo);

    // Must be called when finished
    completionHandler();
}
#endif
////####    iOS 10  End   #########//
```